# error Command failed with exit code 1 with react-native and Xcode library not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when I clone react native project from github,  yarn install,  cd ios && pod install, cd .. ,  yarn ios .  And/or when I ran react-native run-ios as well:

```
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

In addition, when I open the .xcworkspace in the Xcode, I get the error:

```
library not found for BugsnagReactNative
```

The package.json is:

```
  {
  "name": "proj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "build": "CI= npm run build",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/react-native": "^7.16.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.6",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.8",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^4.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.2.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-carousel": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.1.23",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-month-year-picker": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "@bugsnag/source-maps": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The solutions below I tried didn't work.

- yarn add global @bugsnag/react-native-cli
- change rct-folly deployment target to 9.0
- set Build Active architecture Only to Yes
- click and install ios 13.0 simulator in xcode
- delete the search paths in build settings delete pods folder, and installed pods again
- remove all lines in the 'Other Linker Flags' list BUT only if $(inherited) is at the top
- pod update
- reinstall ruby/gem
- uninstall and reinstall Cocoapods
- rm -rf node_modules, yarn cache clean
- remove the podfile.lock and the pod, re-install them
- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi, arch -x86_64 pod install
- uninstall and reinstall watchman
- check node version, react native version, and bugsnag version
- comment out bugsnag dependencies from package. json
- fresh install multiple times

Answer (score -1):

try this

> npx @bugsnag/react-native-cli init

and check bugsnag documentation as you need to have a project available on bugsnag

Comment: how this can be related ?